# OnRender doesn't invoke when a collection item is added?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, dependency-properties

I have a custom control that is used to perform dynamic data rendering.  This control contains a collection of `DataPoint` objects, and each `DataPoint` is rendered in the control based on its position *(the points are drawn in the `OnRender` method).*

The custom control contains many `DependencyProperties` that affect the rendered image, and thus, has `FrameworkPropertyMetadata` that describes that the control should be rendered if the property changes:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DataPointsProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "DataPoints",                                      //Property Name
        typeof(List<DataPoint>),                           //CLR-Property Type
        typeof(MyCustomControl),                           //Custom Control Type
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
            new List<DataPoint>(),                         //Default Value.
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender //Re-render if changed
        )
    );
```

Unfortunately, the re-render does **NOT** occur when a new `DataPoint` is **added** to this collection.

How can I configure the my custom control so that it invokes the `OnRender` method when a new `DataPoint` is added?

The re-render must occur in the WPF designer in addition to the program's run-time.

Comment: Without that **bold** also folks can read the question pretty well.I've edited the question for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, `List<T>` does not support change notifications, and WPF's built-in collections that *do* support change notifications do not derive from `List<T>`.  I suggest using `IList<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>` for your property type.

Second, you will need to add a collection change handler whenever a new collection is assigned to `DataPoints` (after verifying it implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`), and use that handler to call `InvalidateVisual()`.  The simplest way to do this is to specify a property change callback when you register your `DataPoints` dependency property.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DataPointsProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "DataPoints",                                       //Property Name
        typeof(IList<DataPoint>),                            //CLR-Property Type
        typeof(MyCustomControl),                            //Custom Control Type
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
            default(IList<DataPoint>),                      //Default Value.
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, //Re-render if changed,
            OnDataPointsPropertyChanged
        )
    );

private static void OnDataPointsPropertyChanged(
    DependencyObject d,
    DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var control = (MyCustomControl)d;

    var oldValue = e.OldValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;
    var newValue = e.NewValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;

    if (oldValue != null)
        oldValue.CollectionChanged -= control.OnDataPointsCollectionChanged;

    if (newValue != null)
        newValue.CollectionChanged += control.OnDataPointsCollectionChanged;
}

private void OnDataPointsCollectionChanged(
    object s,
    NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    this.InvalidateVisual();
}
```

Lastly, do not specify a collection instance for the default property value: that will cause all instances to share the same collection (unless assigned a new one).  Instead, initialize the property in your constructor:

```
public MyCustomControl()
{
    // ...
    SetCurrentValue(DataPointsProperty, new ObservableCollection<DataPoint>());
}
```

Comment: +1 for reminding me to use SetCurrentValue instead of a local value when initializing a reference type dependency property.

Comment: Great!  It works.  By the way, if the collection has items specified in the XAML, `IList` will not work since it only allows 1 child element (and that child isn't a list item).  However, changing it to `ObservableCollection` allowed me to specify items in XAML.

Comment: A non-generic `IList` should work fine in Xaml, though `IList<T>` may not.  I believe Xaml only supports `IList` and `IAddChild`.

Comment: Yes.  `IList<T>` seems not to work, but `IList` is working as expected.